# In Laravel 9, how can I dispatch a websocket event instantly in production?

Tags: laravel, events, websocket, queue

I am using Laravel 9. I have an auction-style system. When a user bids, I dispatch an AuctionBidPlaced event:

```
class AuctionBidPlaced implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithSockets;
    use SerializesModels;
    use DateTrait;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        public CommunityAuctionBid $bid,
        public ?User $user = null,
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|\Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel[]|string[]|string
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        return new PrivateChannel($this->bid->auction->receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn());
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return [
            ... some data I return ...
        ];
    }
}
```

I call this Event like so:

```
 AuctionBidPlaced::dispatch($bid, $previousLeadingBidUser);
```

`dispatchNow()` and `sync()` don't exist.

In my local environment, this fires instantly. On production, there is a ~10s delay.

My local `QUEUE_DRIVER` is `sync,` and production is `sqs`, but I don't want this to be queued. How can I change my code to guarantee an instant dispatch?

Answer (score 1):

To call the event, follow this format:

```
broadcast(new AuctionBidPlaced($bid, $previousLeadingBidUser));
```

Comment: Hey Ehsan - unfortunately it's still running a ~10s delay unfortunately

Comment: Can you share the ```config/broadcasting.php``` ?

Comment: I don't think it will look pretty in this box, so here's a pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/CLwviXrZ

Comment: Please replace "encrypted" with "useTLS" and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Github is having issues right now causing deploy failures - will let you know when it's working again

Comment: unfortunately the problem persists. I'm starting to think it's perhaps a DevOps issue? Can't see any issue in the code...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any information or solutions at the moment. However, I'll do my best to help you find a solution as quickly as possible.